# when try to split column value to text units and value unit it not work on values have comma separated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I work with SQL Server 2012 and I face am issue: I can't split `Value` column into Text Unit and Value Unit in case I have a `Value` containing multiple values separated by comma.

As an example:

```
Value                    ValueUnit            TextUnit
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1.71V, 2.375V, 3.135V     1.71                 V, 2.375V, 3.135V
```

I have an issue when I try to separate `Value` into to text and value.

It should be like this:

```
       Value                     ValueUnit                TextUnit
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
    1.71V, 2.375V, 3.135V      1.71,2.375,3.135             V
```

For single values without comma as

```
Value  TextUnit ValueUnit
--------------------------
1.8v    V        1.8
```

it works perfectly.

Sample data as below:

```
create table #finaltable
(
    Value nvarchar(50),
    TextUnit nvarchar(50),
    ValueUnit nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #finaltable (Value)
values ('1.71V, 2.375V, 3.135V'),
       ('1.89V, 2.625V, 3.465V'),
       ('1.8V')

update ft 
set ValueUnit = substring(ft.Value, 1, ca.Posit),
    TextUnit = substring (ft.Value, Posit + 1, 50) 
from #FinalTable ft 
cross apply (select PATINDEX('%[0-9.][^0-9.]%', ft.Value)) ca (Posit)  

select * 
from #finaltable
```

When you run the statements above. it will display issue on value have comma separated, on records number 1 and 2, but number 3 it works perfectly.

How to solve this issue for records 1 and 2 that have values with separated by a comma?

Expected result it must be as below

```
Value                     ValueUnit                TextUnit
-------------------------------------------------------------
1.71V, 2.375V, 3.135V    1.71,2.375,3.135           V
1.89V, 2.625V, 3.465V    1.89,2.625,3.465           V
1.8V                      1.8                       V
```

Wrong values as below AND I don't need Below :

```
Value                   TextUnit            ValueUnit
------------------------------------------------------
1.71V, 2.375V, 3.135V   V, 2.375V, 3.135V   1.71       --have issue on this line
1.89V, 2.625V, 3.465V   V, 2.625V, 3.465V   1.89       --have issue on this line
```

Comment: You should move away from storing CSV like this in your SQL tables.

Comment: so what I do please to solve issue

Comment: The table design is **broken**. You need to fix that. Usually the solution is adding another table, with the primary key and _one_ item from the csv column.

Comment: then how to split them to value and unit

Comment: Go find a suitable string splitter, e.g. Jeff Moden's that returns an `Index` for each substring, and use it to split the comma-delimited string into substrings that you can group by source row. Then process each substring to separate the value and unit of the value that is unitized as in many of your other questions. Then put them back together as needed to corrupt them so they are still as far from normalized as you require. (Don't forget to gracefully handle multiple differing units in a single comma-delimited list of valuable units.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, split the values. Then, separate the number from the unit. Then concatenate them back:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #finaltable;

create table #finaltable
(
    Value nvarchar(50),
    ValueXML XML,
    TextUnit nvarchar(50),
    ValueUnit nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #finaltable (Value)
values ('1.71V, 2.375V, 3.135V'),
       ('1.89V, 2.625V, 3.465V'),
       ('1.8V')

UPDATE #finaltable
SET [ValueXML] = '<a>' + REPLACE(Value, ',', '</a><a>')  + '</a>';

WITH DataSource (Value, TextUnit, ValueUnit) AS
(
    SELECT DS.Value
          ,substring(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'varchar(12)'))), 1, ca.Posit)
          ,substring (LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'varchar(12)'))), Posit + 1, 50) 
    FROM #finaltable DS
    CROSS APPLY DS.ValueXML.nodes('a') T(c)
    CROSS APPLY (select PATINDEX('%[0-9.][^0-9.]%', LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'varchar(12)'))))) ca (Posit)  
)
SELECT DISTINCT DS1.[Value]
               ,DS.[Text]
               ,DS1.[ValueUnit]
FROM DataSource DS1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + TextUnit
            FROM DataSource DS2
            WHERE DS2.[Value] = DS1.[Value]
            ORDER BY TextUnit
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(1024)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) DS (Text);
```

[image]

Comment: I tried providing a similar answer but ran into some difficulties, thank goodness there are people like you to help us! :-) Upvote from me!

Comment: Just be careful a bit here.  The XML splitter is as slow as a While Loop and sometimes worse.  The proof can be found at the following article. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function